# Android studio does not search res/xml folder to find usage

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I want to find the usage of a certain string defined in strings.xml file. So, I select the string identifier and click find usage (or Alt+F7 in windows). However, I realized that Android studio does not search the files in res/xml folder (preference.xml) for usage check. Am I doing something wrong, or this is the way it behaves?

Comment: When I am trying to search something i use Ctrl+Shift+F it works better, for me. You only have to select what you want to search and it automatically pastes it on search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Android Studio**

**Step -1**---> **Find Usages**

**Step -2**--> Change  **Selection Scope**

**Step -3**--> Select **Project Production Files**(instead of project files)

**Step -4**-> Click **OK**

**Note :** And its Done ----> Start searching again :-)